# Distorted render in blender 2.9

Tags: rendering

I tried rendering a simple cube today, I literally just went to the top left, and clicked "render image", expecting to see a normal cube. Instead, I got this distorted cube that looks like it is mixing with the background. I really couldn't find any answers to this so I decided to come here. thanks in advance for your help! (please be nice, I just started out)[image]

Comment: this looks like it could be a problem with your graphics driver

Comment: @Allen Simpson really? it seems strange because with all of the renders i tried it’s only a small bit of the shape that is all glitchy like that. do you mean my computer is not supported? or just the driver? because my pc met all of the minimum specs they list on the website

Comment: What's your graphics card?  At different times, for example, there are workarounds for errors in AMD drivers

Comment: i think it’s integrated…

Comment: intel HD graphics 520

Comment: Oh, so you're cpu rendering?

Comment: yeah, basically.

Comment: kind of reminds me of something like this - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191426/white-block-artifacts-using-cycles-and-optix

I'm not aware of any reason cpu rendering should fail on such a trivial example.

Just for future reference, can you edit this info into your question?

Comment: yeah its super weird because my computer can definitely handle it. do you think its maybe a stoftware problem?

Comment: Possibly - software in the sense that you may need to update your graphics driver. Have you tried, or is it for sure up to date?

Comment: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html

Comment: yeah i have checked. they are all up to date